# Repeater - bind a button to a field

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I am displaying 3 jobs by a repeater. Each job has a JOB application ID. In my Data access layer you can delete a job in the database by the ID. So, in any class i can call and delete an entry.

```
JobOpeningDAL app = new JobOpeningDAL();
app.RemoveJobOpening(64);
```

I would like to generate a button for each of the 3+ jobs.

i would like to put this code in the button and not hard code the ID.

Trick is each button would need to get that jobs ID.

Is this possible?

Is there a way to bind a different button to each repeater item based on a item like: JOB ID? That way when the user clicks the delete button underneath a job it automatically deletes it.

Here is my repeater code

```
<br />
 Job ID
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JOBAPPLICATIONID")%>
 <br />
 Job Description: 
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JobDescription") %>
 <br />
 Wage:
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Wage") %>
 <br />
 Department ID:
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "DepartmentID") %>
 <br />
 Has been filled:
 <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HasBeenFilled") %>
 <br />
 Location:
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Location") %>
 <br />

 Job Name:    
  <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "JobName") %>
 <br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand what you are trying to do you could try the following:

add a button to your repeater like this:

```
 <asp:Button ID="yourButton" runat="server"  CommandName="delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id")' />
```

then in your repeater's itemcommand handler, you can do the following:

```
 protected void YourRepeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "delete")
        {
            object idToDelete = e.CommandArgument;
          int  ID = Convert.ToInt32(idToDelete );
             //do stuff with the ID here
       }
       }
```

Comment: i set break points in the repeater function and its not being fired.

Comment: would you mind showing your entire repeater? not just the part you posted in your question. in order for the repeater's itemcommand to fire, there's got to be some kind of reference to the handler.

    <asp:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server"   onitemcommand="MyRepeater_ItemCommand">
do you have something like this in your repeater?